# Update returning queries in ScalikeJDBC

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

With an `implicit val session: DBSession` in scope, concretely as a `scalikejdbc.AutoSession`:

Updates work

```
sql"""
    update payments set status=${status.name} where id in ($ids)
""".update().apply()
```

And selects work

```
sql"""
   select id
   from payments
   where status='valid'
""".map(_.long).list().apply()
```

But an update returning columns fails because the transaction is set as read-only.

```
sql"""
  update payments
  set status='submitted'
  where status='pending'
  and scheduled <= ${ZonedDateTime.now.toInstant}
  returning id
""".map(_.long).iterable().apply().toIterator
```

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction`.

The `session` matches inside `SQLToResult` with an assumption that it should be read only:

```
  case AutoSession | ReadOnlyAutoSession => DB.readOnly(f)
```

I've tried creating my own `DBSession` in order to avoid matching this pattern, but gave up on that approach. The closest I got to getting it working was:

```
val writeableSession: DBSession = DBSession(session.connection, isReadOnly = false)

def inner()(implicit session: DBSession): Iterator[Payment] = {
  sql"""
  update payments
  set status='submitted'
  where status='pending'
  returning id
""".map(_.long).iterable().apply().toIterator
}

inner()(writeableSession)
```

This failed because `session.connection` was `null`.

How can I coerce this to be a localTx instead of readOnly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `AutoSession` behaves as an auto-commit session for DDL and the insert/update/delete ops whereas it works as a read-only session for select queries.

It seems to be doing as follows is the straight-forward way.

```
DB.localTx { implicit session =>
  // Have both the update operation and select query inside this block
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'd prefer to do it this way, but I'm inside playframework with nothing but an eagerly bound Autosession to work with.

Comment: I see. `scalikejdbc.TxBoundary.Future` may be useful for your use cases. http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/transaction.html#futurelocaltx-block

Comment: I'm sorry. Of course, I could invoke `DB.localTx`. I'm not sure why I thought I couldn't. :)